# Prime ideals of $A\times B$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> What are the prime ideals of $A\times B$?

I have proved that if $I\times J$ is a prime ideal, then $I$ and $J$ are prime ideals in the rings $A$ and $B$, respectively. I cannot prove the converse. Actually I want what is Spec(A$\times$B) and its topology.

Comment: If I haven't made any mistakes, if $A$ and $B$ are domains, then if $I \times J$ is a prime ideal, either $I=A$ or $J=B$. Look at the quotient rings.

Comment: A,and B are bot necessarily domians.

Comment: If A or B is not a domain, then there is no prime ideal of $A\times B$.

Comment: why is it true?

Comment: @Hui: This is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideals of $A \times B$ have the form $I \times J$ for ideals $I,J$. We have $(A \times B)/(I \times J) = A/I \times B/J$, this is a domain iff ($A/I=0$ and $B/J$ is a domain) or ($B/J=0$ and $A/I$ is a domain), i.e. iff ($I=A$ and $J$ is a prime ideal) or ($J=B$ and $I$ is a prime ideals). It follows that the canonical map
$$\mathrm{Spec}(A) \sqcup \mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A \times B)$$
induced by the projections $A \times B \to A,B$, is bijective. It maps $A \supseteq I \mapsto I \times B$ and $B \supseteq J \mapsto A \times J$. Actually one can check that it is an isomorphism of ringed spaces.